# What does collocation "hands down" mean?

Tags: collocations

Ussually people use it in the end of the sentence, i think it means somethink like "i admire it" or "i agree with that" but still not sure.

Comment: It can mean a lot of things. Could you provide more context?

Comment: One man talks about other: This man is the best engineer in our team, hands down, other team members thinks the same.

Comment: It basically means *without question* or *without any doubt*. You will find this expression listed in any online dictionary. It's really just a matter of a simple lookup. I don't know what your trouble is: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hands-down

Comment: Got misled by UI of this dictionary http://thinkenglish.me/search?q=hands+down&type=words&date=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hands Down:***

- Easily, little effort, without effort..

Used when talking about whether something is **easily** and best.

Eg: Sachin is hands down the best cricketer ever.

Source : [Hands Down](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hands%20down)